# _.bindAll(this) not working after updating to lodash@4.17.15

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

After finding some npm audit vulnerabilities I updated lodash to version 4.17.15.

After the update `_.bindAll(this);` is not woking in my modules.

How I can fix this? Is there any workaround for fixing this in my entire codebase.

Thanks.

Comment: what version were you on before the upgrade?

Comment: I was using version 3.10.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me as if you're upgrading from version `3.10.1` or earlier: that appears to be when lodash stopped making the second parameter of `bindAll` optional. See the difference between the [current docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.14#bindAll) and the [3.10.1 docs](https://lodash.com/docs/3.10.1#bindAll).

Fortunately if we look at the old [source code](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/51e917b0949de8213003314b8e8074a175c28eb9/lodash.bindall/index.js#L46) it's easy to see how it was handling the optional `methodNames` before: it was using `_.functions()` to provide the list if it was omitted.

```
var bindAll = restParam(function(object, methodNames) {
  methodNames = methodNames.length ? baseFlatten(methodNames) : functions(object);
  // ...
```

The least invasive solution is going to be to monkey-patch lodash to restore that optional logic . That way you don't need to change any of your existing code. Something like this perhaps. You'd want to put this in a script tag immediately following your lodash script tag.

```
(function(_) {
  var bindAll = _.bindAll;
  _.bindAll = function(object, methodNames) {
    if(typeof methodNames==='undefined') methodNames = _.functions(object);
    return bindAll(object, methodNames);
  };
})(_);
```

**However, keep in mind that monkey patching can be dangerous, since you are altering the native functionality of lodash.**

This means that the monkey patch could cause problems during a future lodash upgrade, and it could also be confusing for other developers working on the code in the future.

Comment: How I can do this in nodejs? also I tried `_.bindAll(this, _.functions(this));` as specified here https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/652 but not working. could you please help?

Comment: The function(s) where `bindAll` isn't working, are they by chance `prototype` functions? I noticed earlier when I was playing around with it that it didn't seem to bind the prototype functions. You can tell if this is the case by doing `console.log(_.functions(view.__prot__));` and see if the name of the function you wanted it to bind shows up in the list. (In some rare cases there can be multiple nested prototypes, like `view.__prot__.__prot__`)

Comment: Sorry, just to be clear, `view` is a variable name. In my testing i had a variable named `view`, and I just copied and pasted that code. In your example it would be `_.functions(this.__prot__)`

Comment: Yes it is prototype functions, I'm trying to access member variables using `this` inside prototype functions but it's undefined.

Comment: Also `console.log(_.functions(this));` and `console.log(_.functions(this.__prot__));` returning empty array.

Comment: I also tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.bindall package but not working

Comment: I just happened to notice that there is a [_.functionsIn](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.14#functionsIn) available in lodash, which also captures prototype members. Something like this worked for me: `_.bindAll(this, _.functionsIn(this));`

Comment: `_.bindAll(this, _.functionsIn(this));` this is working for me. Thanks vey much!